# Xtext order-sensitive scoping

Tags: java, scope, xtext

I have a very specific problem with Xtext an Scopes.
My language requires **order sensitive** scoping and I am not sure how I can do that, especially without having to parse every symbol every time some change happens.

Let me give an example:
We have three files, each exporting some symbols and removing some symbols.

File1:

```
Add symbol A, B, C
```

File2:

```
Imports A, B, C from File1
Removes B, C
Adds D
```

File3:

```
Imports A, D from File2
Adds B
```

To complicate things even further, the order of the files is given by a version number in each file and the imports are implicit.

I already had a look at the [Xtext Documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/303_runtime_concepts.html#scoping), but when it comes to global scoping, I find the documentation to be not very helpful. Is there some starting point I could have a look at?

Thanks in advance for any tips or hints :)

Answer (score 1):

The default global scope will make the symbols from all files visible to all other files in the same project. A possible solution is to leave the scoping as it is and implement your custom behavior in the linking phase: subclass DefaultLinkingService and override `getLinkedObjects(...)`. Use the scope to get a list of all declared symbols for a given name. Then you can choose one of these symbols based on the order-sensitive semantics of your files.

If you need additional information on the file containing a declared symbol, you can put it into the *user data* of the IEObjectDescription: subclass DefaultResourceDescriptionStrategy, override `createEObjectDescriptions(...)`, and use `EObjectDescription.create(...)` to create descriptions with arbitrary String → String mappings. These mappings can be read in the linking service and other services without the need to resolve the corresponding EObjects.

The drawback of this linking-based approach is that you'll have to customize the content assist proposal provider in order to filter out symbols according to the file semantics. The default proposal provider will offer all symbols it finds in the scope.